# What does <...> mean in FT8?

Tags: ft8

I caught this in FT8, did someone just enter `<...>` as their call sign or is this code for something?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the WSJT-X documentation:

> Angle brackets imply that the enclosed callsign is not transmitted in
> full, but rather as a hash code using a smaller number of bits.
> Receiving stations will display the full nonstandard callsign if it
> has been received in full in the recent past. Otherwise it will be
> displayed as <...>.

https://wsjt.sourceforge.io/wsjtx-doc/wsjtx-main-2.7.0-rc2.html#COMP-CALL

This is an interesting read about FT8 callsign hashes: http://www.dx.nl/?p=1478